# How to place the text top left in a table cell

Tags: tables, positioning, height, text

We can use

`\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}`

to increase the height of rows. The text, however, is just in the center.

How can we simply put it on the top-left, as in the second and third columns in the picture?

Note: this is drawn by Tikz. I want it with tabular if possible.

[image: 3 columns]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is simple to achieve by use of the `tabularray` package. It define `belowskip` option for setting vertical distance below cells contents:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
              colspec = {*{3}{c}},
             belowsep = 12mm,
             }
a) T.Insert(8) & b) T.Insert(12) & c) T.Insert(10)  \\
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:**
Let me add top left alignment of cell contents. I is visible, if cell's width is bigger than that this text width. Assuming that all cells have the same width and that table width is equal to `\textwidth`, than the cells specifier should be `X[l]}`. That new positioning of text in cell is better visible, let add package `geometry` for wider text area:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
              colspec = {*{3}{X[l]}},
             belowsep = 12mm,
             }
a) T.Insert(8) & b) T.Insert(12) & c) T.Insert(10)  \\
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice, Today it hit 2500 views, and I've corrected some typos on the question and got a different approach.

Comment: @kelalaka, I didn't see your question before. this solution is  possible recent  two years or so.  Anyway, answer is not only "nice" but "excellent"   :-)  [just a joke, nice is just fine]

Comment: :) thanks for the information. I'll look at the package. I was building an exam-style for my needs.

Comment: @kelalaka, recent version of package is 2022B. It was published Jun 1, 2022. It is based on LaTeX3 project. To my opinion is very powerful, but with a little bit different syntax from "classic" packages for tables. Syntax is easy to learn.

Comment: Note that texts are not on the center, they need to be top-left so that rest of the box is space for the student/lecturerer solution.

Comment: @kelalaka, see addendum to answer. You only need to change column specifier (from`` to `X[l]`

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution is to modify the contents of the cell,  The first solutions added a "strut" extending downward, while the second shows a more general approach using `\raisebox`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
\rule[-2\normalbaselineskip]{0pt}{3\normalbaselineskip}% strut
a) T.Insert(8) & b) T.Insert(12) & c) T.Insert(10) \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\bigskip
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
\raisebox{\normalbaselineskip}{a) T.Insert(8)} & 
\raisebox{0pt}[2\normalbaselineskip][1.6\normalbaselineskip]{b) T.Insert(12)} &% baseline here
\raisebox{-\normalbaselineskip}{c) T.Insert(10)} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: tabulars]

Comment: It doesn't look like a real solution. It looks like a workaround. Could we just say that in normal circumstances there is no easy way to align cell content top-left? You always have to use typographic "tricks". Isn't it that way?

Comment: @bulitz - All of LaTeX is based on typographical tricks.  There is strut automatically added whose size is determined by \arraystretch.  If you want to modify the source code you could have a real solution.  But in the end, both would be doing the exact same thing.